# Доброго времени суток, пишу бота для тг с библиотекой pytelegrambot и столкнулся с проблемой, кнопки на данном этапе просто не выводятся

Tags: python, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAEBAAEuZP0FXTHr-mLaFXinBXQv7v0SIPoAApcYAAI9rqlJObvmILuhMxwwBA')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Здарова слоняра!\n\nЯ был создан, чтобы помочь тебе</b>', parse_mode='html')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'<b>Забыл, что задали?</b>',parse_mode='html')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'<b>Или Хочешь добавить домашку :3</b>',parse_mode='html')


    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    HT = types.KeyboardButton('Узнать домашку')
    add = types.KeyboardButton('Добавить домашку')
    markup.add(HT, add)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ReplyKeyboardMarkup` - это класс пользовательской клавиатуры. Он должен быть отправлен вместе с вашим последним сообщением как параметр `reply_markup`. Код будет выглядеть вот так.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    HT = types.KeyboardButton('Узнать домашку')
    add = types.KeyboardButton('Добавить домашку')
    markup.add(HT, add)

    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAEBAAEuZP0FXTHr-mLaFXinBXQv7v0SIPoAApcYAAI9rqlJObvmILuhMxwwBA')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Здарова слоняра!\n\nЯ был создан, чтобы помочь тебе</b>', parse_mode='html')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'<b>Забыл, что задали?</b>',parse_mode='html')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'<b>Или Хочешь добавить домашку :3</b>',parse_mode='html',reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling()
```